# executing a statement built from values in a table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

is it possible to do this? (I'm a SAS programmer usually so am used to building code in SAS macros like this). I have a table (lets call it TableCode) that holds lines of code (dynamically built by previous queries from metadata etc), e.g.

```
code               pos
----               ---
a.id as id_a,      1
b.id as id_b,      2
a.var1 as var1_a,  3
b.var1 as var_b    4
from tablea a,     991
join tableb b      992
on a.id=b.id;      993
```

it would be bigger than that but you get the idea. 
So, I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
execute 'select '||code||' from TableCode order by pos';
```

meaning that the code stored in TableCode would run. Is such a thing possible with Redshift?

Comment: Postgres or Redshift? Although they share some ancient roots, they are two very different database products.

Comment: Hmm, well its PostgreSQL in a Redshift environment? Claims to to be based on PostgreSQL but won't allow one to build functions, for example, only procedures, so there are some limitations sadly

Comment: There  is no such thing as "Postgres in a Redshift environment". It's **either** Postgres **or** Redshift. And this is important for your question because in Postgres this would be possible with dynamic SQL in a stored function - which you can't do in Redshift.

Comment: What tool are you using to submit your Redshift queries? Why not have that tool build the code from the data and send it to Redshift.  For example you could use SAS to do that.

Comment: SAS can't communicate with our Redshift database. I'm using SQL Workbench if that helps ... How would one do this in PostgreSQL?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Run your query to generate the code as the result of the query.  Copy the text generated and paste it back into your SQL Workbench editor window. Submit it.